# user input the number of lines and starting number in java pattern problems

Tags: java, for-loop, numbers

can anyone help me with this? I am doing this pattern problem in which the user inputs the Starting Number and Number of Lines.
here is my code:

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int sn, nl;

 try
    {
        System.out.print("Enter Starting Number: ");
        sn = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.print("Enter Number of Lines: ");
        nl = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        
        for(int i=nl; i>=sn; i--)
        {
            for(int j=i; j>=sn; j--)
            {
                System.out.print(i + " ");
            } 
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        
    }`
```

the result should be:
Starting number: 5
Number of Lines: 4

```
  8 8 8 8
  7 7 7
  6 6
  5
```

but im getting no output from my code.
And if i change my Starting number and number of lines to 5 and 6.
i aam getting this result:

```
  6 6
  5
```

Comment: Can you provide the variable declarations and the data that is being read in to the BufferedReader?

Comment: Think about what this does `for(int i=nl; i>=sn; i--)` why are you mixing up nl and sn, also what about this `for(int j=i; j>=sn; j--)` specifically `j=i`. Also do something with your catch Exception otherwise you don't know why it might be failing `catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}`

Comment: @RStevoUK
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        
           int sn, nl;

The sn is Starting Number while the nl is Number of Lines

Comment: @sorifiend noted mate

Answer (score 0):

The issues comes from the mixing and matching of the `nl` and `sn` parameters in your for loops and how the print number is shown.

First specify a separate printNumber that starts from the maximum `int printNumber = sn + nl;`, then inside the first for loop we can decrease it for every loop `printNumber--;`

Next the first loop should only focus on the number of lines, for example `for(int i=nl; i>0; i--)`

The second loop should only focus on the number of items to print in each line, for example `for(int j=i; j>0; j--)`, note how we can use `j=i` here because the first loop is now working correctly in a descending order.

Then all together it might look something like this:

```
int printNumber = sn + nl;

for(int i=nl; i>0; i--)
{
    printNumber--;
    for(int j=i; j>0; j--)
    {
        System.out.print(printNumber + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Output whet `nl = 4` and `sn = 5`;

```
8 8 8 8 
7 7 7 
6 6 
5
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. We have to print numbers for sl lines.
2. We will start the loop with decreasing order of sl (5 --> 4 --> 3 --> 2 --> 1).
3. Each iteration of sl will have a number that is 1 minus the addition of sn and sl. This is because sn is inclusive.
4. And in the same iteration, you need to print that calculated number (in point 3) for sl times. For example: if sl is 6 then you have to print the calculated number for 6 times. And in the next decremented iteration which is 5 now, will need to print calculated number for 5 times and so on..

Solution:

```
private static void solution(int sn, int sl) {
    while (sl > 0){
        int printNum = (sn + sl) - 1;
        for (int j = 1; j <= sl; j++) {
            System.out.print(printNum + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        sl--;
    }
}
```